# expanding/collapsing text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I want to expand a text I always use this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(".readMore").bind("click", function () {
    jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text() == "Leer más" ? "Ocultar" : "Leer más");
    jQuery(this).prev().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

and HTML code like the following:

```
<div class="alwaysDisplay"><b>Text to display always</b></div>
<div class="expandText">Text to expand</div>
<div class="readMore">Leer más</div>
```

So, I can display the hidden text clicking on the text "Leer más".

My problem is that using this code, the web shows something like:

```
Text to display always

Leer más
```

But I would like to display something like:

```
Text to display always Leer más
```

I mean, the "button" to expand in the same line. I guess that the problem is that when I use a div label, it displays the text in the next line. How could I display the "button" Leer más in the same line?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `div` is a `block` element. Either set the `display` property to `inline-block` or use a different element like `span` which is an `inline` element.

```
.alwaysDisplay, .expandText {
   display: inline-block; 
}
```

Your markup is not semantic, you shouldn't use the `div`s for everything, for text contents one uses `p` element. For buttons either `button` or `a` element should be used:

A suggestion:

HTML:

```
<p class="text_content">
    <b>Text to display always</b>
    <span class="hidden_text">Text to expand</span>
</p>
<a href='#' class='read_more'>read more</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.read_more').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(function(_, currentText){
        return currentText === 'read more' ? 'read less' : 'read more';
    }).prev().find('.hidden_text').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7p8v/

Comment: Thanks BlackSheep, could you tell me how to use the property inline-block in my example? Thanks you very much again.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and for your advices, @BlackSheep. I am going to try to use them.